# Executar programa no Debian compilado no Ubuntu com Lazarus

Tags: lazarus, linux

Quando compilo qualquer fonte desenvolvido em Lazarus no Ubuntu, no mesmo executa normalmente, mas no Debian com o comando `./Programa`, dá o seguinte erro: "Falha de segmentação". O programa pode ser o mais simples que for, mesmo só exibindo uma simples saída de texto. Os sistemas possuem a mesma arquitetura de 32 bits. Será ausência de alguma biblioteca ou incompatibilidade? Eu não tenho como compilar diretamente no Debian, pois se trata de um VPS e tenho acesso somente por SSH.

Segue o código fonte:

```
program Programa;

uses
  SysUtils;

var
iParam: string;

begin
  iParam := ParamStr(1);
  Writeln(iParam);
end.
```